# different clustering labels

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to cluster new data that have not been seen during the training and only including in the testing data. The training file has five classes whereas the testing data has 7 classes (5 +2) where the 2 are new classes. Now, I want to run k-mean to find a the proper cluster to the new add classes or create new cluster for each if they are not close to any cluster.

This is a part of my code:

```html
print("Reading training data...")
#mydata = pd.read_csv('.\KDDTrain.csv', header=0)
mydata = pd.read_csv('.\PTraining.csv', header=0)

# select all but the last column as data
X_train = mydata.ix[1:, :-1]
X_train = np.array(X_train)
n_samples, n_features = np.shape(X_train)
# print np.shape(X_train)

# select last column as target/class
y_train = mydata.ix[1:, n_features]
y_train = np.array(y_train)

# encode target labels with numeric values from 0 to no of classes
# print "Encoding class labels..."
from sklearn import preprocessing

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(y_train)
# print list(label_encoder.classes_)
# print 'total no of classes in dataset=' + str(len(label_encoder.classes_))
y_train = label_encoder.transform(y_train)

# n_samples, n_features = data.shape
n_digits = len(np.unique(y_train))

print("Training data statistics")
print("n_attack_catagories: %d, \t n_samples %d, \t n_features %d"
      % (n_digits, n_samples, n_features))

sample_size = 300

# Read test data
mytestdata = pd.read_csv('.\KDDTest+.csv', header=0)

print("Reading test data...")
# select all but the last column as data
X_test = mytestdata.ix[1:, :-1]
X_test = np.array(X_test)
# print np.shape(X_test)

# select last column as target/class
y_test = mytestdata.ix[1:, n_features]
# print "actual labels"
# print y_test
y_test = label_encoder.transform(y_test)
# print "Encoded labels"
# print y_test
y_test = np.array(y_test)

n_samples_test, n_features_test = np.shape(X_test)
n_digits_test = len(np.unique(y_test))
print("Test data statistics")
print("n_attack_catagories: %d, \t n_samples %d, \t n_features %d"
      % (n_digits_test, n_samples_test, n_features_test))

print(79 * '_')
```

and giving this error

```html
File "C:/Users/aalsham4/PycharmProjects/clusteringtask/clustering.py", line 87, in <module>
    y_test = label_encoder.transform(y_test)
  File "C:\Users\aalsham4\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 153, in transform
    raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" % str(diff))
ValueError: y contains new labels: ['calss6' 'class7' ]
```

Now, I'm not sure If I am doing this correctly to cluster labeled classes or not.

Any suggestion

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  In particular, we can't reproduce the problem without the data files.

Comment: I have to files one contains training data and another contains testing data, the testing data file has 7 classes and the training data file only 5 classes. I would like to apply k-means clustering to find if these two classes are similar or not to any of the 5 classes that my module trained on.
Is this applicable or not?

Comment: If you have classes, use a classifier, not k-means. Wrong tool for your problem. And don't use the KDDCup99 data, it's flawed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anony-Mousse already said, this is not a k-means problem.  k-means is to find the "natural" groupings, given the number of classes you want.  Once you assign those labels, further updates are no longer a k-means problem.

You can use a variety of statistical analysis heuristics to decide whether a new class is "sufficiently close" to an existing class.  This usually uses measures of mean and deviation (which you already have for the k-means classes), density, and anything else you find pertinent to your problem.

I suggest that you research spectral clustering algorithms, and try them on the entire data set; those are better-suited at finding gaps, reacting to density, etc. (depending on the algorithm you choose for this application).